# What is the relationship of an Arduino .ino file to main.cpp?

Tags: arduino-ide, c++

Is the `.ino` file an alternative from a `main.cpp` file?

If yes, then could someone mind explaining the structure of the `.ino` file in `main.cpp` and its relationship?

Comment: ... ... What ... ... ?

Comment: No need to put on hold. English is not my native language, and I had no problem with the question.

Comment: As well, closure is usually applied for obviously off-topic questions or worse infractions. Why was this closed rather than just held for clarification? Voting to re-open.

Comment: @JRobert, the Answer by Jot is good. The Question should be edited.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Arduino uses the gcc compiler. That compiler wants a normal `main` function of course. Arduino has put a layer on top of that with `setup` and `loop`.

The hidden `main` function for basic Arduino boards is in [main.cpp](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/main.cpp) (click on it to see it).
You see that `init` is called, and `setup` and `loop` and a few other things.

To learn how to use `setup` and `loop`, you can try a few examples. They are in the menu of the Arduino IDE and they are also online.

The .ino files are all combined together and presented to the compiler as a single .cpp file to compile. The Arduino libraries are compiled from source as well, and everything is linked into a binary.

When you know how to use `setup` and `loop`, try the [Blink Without Delay example](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay). It can be used to run different software timers and do all kind of tasks and keep everything running smooth.

Comment: It solves my query, thanks for explaining the int main function in main.cpp. Also I would try the blink w/o delay example as you suggested.

Comment: The link to main.cpp has moved to a new repository, [here is the new location](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/main.cpp).

Comment: @LukeBayes Thanks, I have adjusted the link in my answer. The old standard avr has been moved to "ArduinoCore-avr".